# Alternative to display flex for event tracker

Tags: html, css, styles

I currently have an event tracker made using `html` and `css`. My issue is that I would like to get ride of `display: flex;` due to browser-compatibility issues. Is there an alternative to achieve the same result? I tried using `display:inline-block` because without `flex` all steps were coming in different lines.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row event">
    <div class="col-xs-3 event-step">
        <p class="event-stepnum">Step 1</p>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 event-step complete">
        <p class="event-stepnum">Step 2</p>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 event-step">
        <p class="event-stepnum">Step 3</p>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.event > .event-step {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.event > .event-step .event-stepnum {
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.steps .step-on,
.steps .step-done {
  background-color: #1b7e28;
  color: #1b7e28;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.progress {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 5px;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.progress > .progress-bar {
  width: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: #fbe8aa;
}

.event-step.complete > .progress > .progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display:flex;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23649/)**

Comment: Correct [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23649/)

Comment: @abhi thanks... I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `display:flex` by `display:inline-block` and give your step divs a fixed width:

```
.event > .event-step {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.row {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/onk2cqhg/